# What's the proper value for "guard" and "middleware" in config/fortify.php file for a SPA?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am building a single page application (SPA), I have followed the Laravel official document to use Fortify with Sanctum.

From the "SPA Authentication" section on sanctum page (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)

For a SAP, I need to use 'web' for "guard" attribute, but it didn't mention what is the proper value for "middleware" attribute?

And because it instructs you to add `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class` to the api middleware group within `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

So I assume I should use `['api']` for the middleware? What is the proper value for a SPA?

Comment: You use the sanctum guard: Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function...

Comment: @NICO yes, I understand that and I am using it in my route/api.php. And it works fine whether the value is `['web']` or `['api']` for `middleware` in fortify.php, so I just want to figure out the right setting.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it in the meantime?